# Не знаю как сделать social bar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Доброго времени суток. Не знаю как сделать такой сошиал бар ( правый нижний угол ):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после с номером, и странами у меня же есть, не понимаю как сделать чтобы при нажатии на иконку выежало поле ( там где нужно вводить номер телефона ). В не активном состоянии это просто иконка с телефоном. После нажатия она выежает вправо, одталкивает другие иконки в лево. При нажатии на другую иконку, та заежает на зад, выежает вторая ( такое нужно только для телефона и емейла ).

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. А вы смотрели как устроен этот бар? Ну потыкать его , поменять че нить? Как по мне это единственный способ узнать как он работает. Выглядит как css анимация + немного js для управления z-index.

Comment: @alexoander это макет, я не могу ничего потыкать, уже бы забрал его если бы мог) Не могу ничего придумать вот и обратился сюда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("div").hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("overEveryone");
});
```

```css
.ha div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: green;
  /*transition-property: background-color;*/
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.ha div:not(:nth-child(1)) {
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.b2 {
  z-index: 10;
}

.b3 {
  z-index: 11;
}

.b1 {
  z-index: 1;
}

div .overEveryone {
  margin:0 20px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ha">
  <div class="b1">1</div>
  <div class="b2">2</div>
  <div class="b3 ">3</div>
</div>
```

Это примерный набросок того, с чего можно начать. Тут еще много можно поиграться с анимацией, но смысл надеюсь понятен.

Comment: чувак, ты лучший, спасибо